# Trying to edit a WP site locally using MAMP

Tags: database, local-installation

I'm new to WordPress. A friend asked me to redesign his WP blog and I've installed it on my Mac using MAMP. I went through the database setup and imported the site's existing DB and added the tables. It all looks good, as far as I can tell, on the phpMyAdmin site.

When I go to url "localhost" in Chrome (and other browsers) I see the blog's front page, which is definitely local, but if I try to login, I'm sent back online. This also happens if I click on any of the links in the blog.

I've check that wp-config.php DB_NAME matches the name of the DB I downloaded. Anyone got any ideas what's going on?

Thanks
Gavin

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

That will define your site URL as whatever happens to be in the browser location bar. Very useful for moving a site from server to server without actually changing the siteurl and home location in the database. Just don't leave this on a production site.

Dalton

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it! It would be great if you could mark this as the accepted answer so others can find it as well.